# Excel Macro to create 8 character username

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm trying to use an Excel VBA macro to create an eight character username and what I came up with fails.  If entered in a cell, the formulas seem to work.  In my spreadsheet, I have the last name in B6, First name in C6, and middle initial in D6.  The results go in G6.  If the last name and first name length is <8, then the middle initial will be included in the user name.  Here's what I have:

```
Sub Macro1()

' Macro1 Macro

Range("G6").Select

If Len(B6) >= 7 Then
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LOWER(CONCATENATE(LEFT(RC[-5],7),LEFT(RC[-4],1))"
Else
'    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LOWER((LEFT(RC[-5],7)&LEFT(RC[-4],(8-LEN(RC[-5])))))"

End If

End Sub
```

I haven't tackled adding the middle initial to a short password yet.  That's secondary to the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would create a user defined function for this, that way you don't need a sub to output a worksheet function

For this you would just enter in G6 `=username(C6,D6,G6)`. The added benefit is the increased readability of the code for maintenance and reading your values into the macro immediately and not needing to reference any cells.

```
Public Function UserName(ByVal firstName As String, ByVal lastName As String, ByVal middleInitial As String) As String
    Dim result As String
    If Len(firstName) + Len(lastName) >= 8 Then
        result = firstName & lastName
    Else: result = firstName & middleInitial & lastName
    End If

    If Len(result) > 8 Then result = Left(result, 8)

    UserName = result
End Function
```

This can also be reused pretty easily for other similar functions because it's easy to read.

You can use the same type of code if you want to keep it as a sub by just `Dim`ing the variables and setting them to their respective cells.

An important note on the logic of this function - in your attempt you don't account for the possibility that a first + middle + last is less than 8, so I don't know what you would want to do with that. Maybe your max is 8 so it doesn't matter if it's 5 - but if it does, add some logic in adding characters. Also, if this is generating usernames you'll probably want to check it against existing usernames and adjust for duplicates.

Comment: Thansks; very helpful.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Rich if it works please be sure to click the green checkmark next to the answer to mark the question complete.